# Q_ASSERT - "Incorrect format specifier"

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `Q_ASSERT()`:

```
Q_ASSERT(QString("%1").arg(0) != "0");
```

When it fails, it shows an Abort/Retry/Ignore message box, but in the text it says:

```
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\output.c
Line: 1120
Expression: ("Incorrect format specifier", 0)
```

With this call stack:

```
0   _output_s_l output.c    1120    0x5dbee38d  
1   _vsnprintf_helper   vsprintf.c  140 0x5dbb00e8  
2   _vsnprintf_s_l  vsprintf.c  288 0x5dbb0610  
3   _vsnprintf_s    vsprintf.c  340 0x5dbb0880  
4   _VCrtDbgReportA dbgrptt.c   301 0x5dc2571e  
5   _CrtDbgReportV  dbgrpt.c    241 0x5dc24992  
6   _CrtDbgReport   dbgrpt.c    258 0x5dc2494b  
7   qt_message_output   qglobal.cpp 2232    0x5d43bacf  
8   qt_message  qglobal.cpp 2298    0x5d43bc69  
9   qFatal  qglobal.cpp 2481    0x5d43c059  
10  qt_assert   qglobal.cpp 1999    0x5d43b629
```

But if I change it to:

```
Q_ASSERT(QString("0").arg(0) != "0");
```

It works as expected, showing

```
File: global\qglobal.cpp
Line: 2232

ASSERT: "QString("0").arg(0) != "0"" in file ..\MyProject\tester.cpp, line 132
```

So why this strange behavior, is it a bug in Qt?

Comment: Ouch. If that's being fed to printf without sanitation, you indeed have a problem...

Comment: You mean they are doing `printf(message)` instead of `printf("%s", message)`?

Comment: OK, I'm looking at the source - http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/0c03af0d4d928bdbb32b09eedb1dba3ce59e5278:src/corelib/global/qglobal.cpp#L2268

Comment: Looks like something like that indeed. Not familiar with the Windows API, but it does appear that it's being used as a format string.

Comment: Fugidabout assert, what about using `!=` to compare C strings?

Comment: @Mat That's the line they use from source - `int ret = _CrtDbgReport(_CRT_ERROR, __FILE__, __LINE__, QT_VERSION_STR, buf);`, buf is `const char *buf`.

Comment: @HotLicks that is accounted for with overloaded operators (arg() returns a QString and that has a [`operator==(const char*)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#operator-eq-eq-2) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug in Qt, in [qt_message_output](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/0c03af0d4d928bdbb32b09eedb1dba3ce59e5278%3asrc/corelib/global/qglobal.cpp#L2268-2347) they have this line:

```
int ret = _CrtDbgReport(_CRT_ERROR, __FILE__, __LINE__, QT_VERSION_STR, buf);
```

Should have been

```
int ret = _CrtDbgReport(_CRT_ERROR, __FILE__, __LINE__, QT_VERSION_STR, "%s", buf);
```

They are passing the entire line contained in `Q_ASSERT()` as a format specifier.